# Its returning a error, but its in try-catch. Whats the error?

Tags: android, try-catch

My code want it surrounded bt a try-catch. I did it, but it continue with a error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.parse(SimpleDateFormat.java:1001) at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:624)
```

This is my code:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");
try{
    Date date = sdf.parse(dataUltima);
    dataUltima = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm").format(date);

} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: The try-catch block is looking to catch a `ParseException`, not a `NullPointerException`. It seems that the variable `sdf` is `null`. Try changing lower-case `hh` in the format to `HH`.

Comment: Where do you instantiate dataUltima?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is only catching `ParseException`, so a NullPointerException won't be handled by the catch clause.  My guess would be that either `sdf` is null when this code executes, or `dataUltima` is null when it is passed into the parse method (I don't exactly remember how `parse()` responds to null arguments).

You can solve this in a number of ways.  Check to see if the variable causing the exception is null before executing the try block, add a catch for `NullPointerException` to your try/catch, or make the `ParseException` block catch a more generic exception (like `Exception`) to handle both cases (although I personally would not recommend it).

Comment: I debbuged and the the dataUltima is null. Thats is the problem. I just dont know why is null. But thanks anyway

Comment: Thanks for the help. dataUltima was null. Now its working. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

dataUltima is probably null when you try to do this `Date date = sdf.parse(dataUltima);` and your catch only gets `ParseException`. If you want to catch all errors, Change `ParseException` to `Exception`.

Answer (score 0):

That is a NullPointerException, your code only catch the ParseException.
check your date variable, i think its null.
you can catch this exception doing something like that

```
try{
    Date date = sdf.parse(dataUltima);
    dataUltima = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm").format(date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");
try{
    Date date = sdf.parse(dataUltima);
    dataUltima = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm").format(date);

} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Look for reason for null pointer in line 624 and have u referenced dataUltima anywhere with its class..??

Comment: Yes, I did it. I debbuged and the the dataUltima is null. Thats is the problem. I just dont know why is null. But thanks anyway